# PowerDesigner References symbols are auto-aligning when I don't want them to move

Tags: powerdesigner

I'm using PowerDesigner 16.6. I have a Physical diagram with 26 tables but they are quite referenced between each other. First I have used an auto-align option but then I have changed some references layouts for a even better reading-ability.

Now when I want to add a new reference several of the lines are automatically changed. Is there a way how freeze/lock the references symbols?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how adding a Reference can trigger other Reference symbols move. Do you move the Table symbol? In Tools > Display Preferences > General Settings, I see the Automatic Link Routing which may be related to the behaviour you witness, if you selected it.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :)